# Android; fragments overlap when switching tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

First off, thank you all for this great community.

I am attempting to following the support demos sample code for implementing a tabbed-fragment interface.

Top level, I am trying to implement two tabs, associate a single fragment with each tab and have the fragments appear when each tab is selected accordingly.

Currently, I have two issues (but I am sure they're related...)

1) **The fragments for each tab are overlapping each other.** This could be related to improper fragment attach/detach.

2) **A third mystery fragment is being created somewhere and overlapping the other fragments as well**

---

### On the emulator (and on a physical device), you can see there are two fragments overlapping when either tab is selected

**When tab1 is selected,** fragment 1 and the unknown fragment are overlapping.

**When tab2 is selected,** fragment 1 and fragment 2 are overlapping.

---

**Links to the screenshots (not enough reputation to upload photos... )**

(tab1 overlapping) http://s8.postimg.org/kv81yz745/tab1_overlapping.png

(tab2 overlapping) http://s8.postimg.org/3tf7wvs91/tab2_overlapping.png

---

**here, I've separated the text in each fragment for demo/clarity purposes.**

**Links to these screenshots are below in my comment/response. (not enough reputation to upload more than 2 links... )**

### Activity layout (fragment_tabs.xml)

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

### Source code

```
public class TabbedInfoHome extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

TabHost mTabHost;
TabManager mTabManager;

static String tag1name = "simple1";
static String tag2name = "simple2";

static String tab1string = "You are looking at fragment 1";
static String tab2string = "You are looking at fragment 2";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
        Fragment frag1 = CountingFragment.newInstance(tab1string);
        Fragment frag2 = CountingFragment.newInstance(tab2string);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, frag1, tag1name);
        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, frag2, tag2name);

        ft.commit();
    } 
    else {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }    

    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag1name)
                .setIndicator(tag1name),
                TabbedInfoHome.CountingFragment.class,
                null);

    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag2name)
                .setIndicator(tag2name),
                TabbedInfoHome.CountingFragment.class, 
                null);
}   

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

public static class CountingFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    String displayString;
    String FRAGMENT_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();



    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static CountingFragment newInstance(String toDisplay) {
        CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("string", toDisplay);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

     /* When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        displayString = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("string") : "no string was passed in!";
    }


    /* The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        boolean separateStrings = false;

        /* the overlapping is hard to decipher, so
         *  lets illustrate how both fragments are appearing */
        if(separateStrings) {

            String temp;

            /* b/c I only created TWO instances of the CountingFragments object, 
             *  there should only be TWO "displayStrings" to consider...
             */
            if( (displayString.compareTo(tab1string) == 0) ) {
                /* user clicked tab 1 */
                temp = "\n\n\n\n" + displayString;
            }
            else if( (displayString.compareTo(tab2string) == 0) ) {
                /* user clicked tab2 */
                temp = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + displayString;
            }
            else {
                /* unknown CountingFragment instance */
                temp = "What am I doing here..??? ";
            }

            ((TextView)tv).setText(temp);

        }
        else {
            /* normal case of the fragment being shown; (but they overlap!) */
            ((TextView)tv).setText(displayString);
        }


        return v;
    }
}

/**
 * This is a helper class that implements a generic mechanism for
 * associating fragments with the tabs in a tab host.  It relies on a
 * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
 * between fragments.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
 * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabManager supplies its own dummy
 * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
 * care of switch to the correct fragment shown in a separate content area
 * whenever the selected tab changes.
 */
public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final int mContainerId;
    private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> mTabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    TabInfo mLastTab;

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, int containerId) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mContainerId = containerId;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);


        if (info.fragment != null ) {  // && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            Log.d("addingTab", "we already have a fragment for this tab. tabInfo.fragment.id: " + info.fragment.getId());
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        // associate the tabSpec tag with a particular TabInfo object
        mTabs.put(tag, info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);

        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);

                    ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Screenshots of the two overlapping fragments, separated for demo/clarity        (tab1 separated) http://s8.postimg.org/gorsxdww5/tab1_separated.png

(tab2 separated) http://s8.postimg.org/az6yzc1c5/tab2_separated.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After days of experimenting, I got this to work properly.

In the `onCreate` method of my `TabbedInfoHome` class, when creating new instances of the fragments for the first time (`savedInstanceState == null`), I forced the execution of pending transactions in the FragmentTransaction using `this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`

This explanation is based a bit off the documentation found at:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()

> *After a `FragmentTransaction` is committed with `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, it is scheduled to be executed **asynchronously** > on the process's main thread. If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this function.*

One outstanding question I still have is how the lack of immediate pending transactions execution manifests itself into the behavior seen in the original question.

**In other words... how does the *LACK* of `this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` explain the overlapping fragments?**

---

### **Edited code is below; one line addition**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs); 

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
    Fragment frag1 = CountingFragment.newInstance(tab1string);
    Fragment frag2 = CountingFragment.newInstance(tab2string);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, frag1, tag1name);
    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, frag2, tag2name);

    ft.commit();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();      // <----- This is the key 
} 
else {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
}    

mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup();

mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag1name)
            .setIndicator(tag1name),
            TabbedInfoHome.CountingFragment.class,
            null);

mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag2name)
            .setIndicator(tag2name),
            TabbedInfoHome.CountingFragment.class, 
            null);
}
```

Comment: I think it should be said that my usage with the SherlockActivity had nothing to do with this issue. Thanks

Comment: `executePendingTransactions()` did not solve my same problem with a `DrawerLayout` and a `NavigationView`. If I switch too quickly of `Fragment`, they will still overlap (yes, only then)...

Answer (score 1):

I also get this problem on Nexus 5.

I think we have the other solution better than remove solution by using this way.

In `all your xml files`, should define the background color for it, it will solve the problem :

Add this `android:background="@android:color/black"` in to the View tag you defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same and this morning had the same problems. I resolve them with the info I got from another question similar.

In my case I'm not using SherlockActionBar, but the solution must work to you.

In the part where you check to see if there is a fragment inflated for the tab I use:

```
             // in order to avoid fragment 
     Fragment prevFragment;
        FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
        prevFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(mTag); 
        if (prevFragment != null) { 
            mFragment = prevFragment; 
        } // \previous Fragment management
```

I suppose this must work for you if you adequate it to the SherlockActionBar commands (cos where I read the info they used with SherlockActionBar).

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you @mrgdiez for the response. I wasn't able to quite figure out how your fix fits into my original code?  Also, you mentioned that you got some information from another similar question. Would you post the link to that question so that others that read this post can maybe refer to it as well? Thanks again for the response though!!

Comment: Hello @Jimmy Ng, I didn't post the link because when I answered your question, I didn't find it any more... I'm in the middle of a project and I have almost no time... I'm so sorry for my answer, when I first read your question I supposed it was the same problem I had but now I realized is not. I'm a beginner with Android so sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Already many solutions are given but i wasn't able to resolve the issue, because of a silly mistake. Problem was, In new SDK by default Activity's are extended  to "ActionbarActivity" in which fragment's get created but they overlap. To resolve it ,extends your activity to "FragmentActivity"